# Python Key Logger with Duration and Multiple Keys

Tags: python

I am trying to write a key logger in python that determines the length of time a key is pressed - key pressed through release - while also detecting if another key is pressed. For example, someone presses w for 4 seconds. While holding W, they also press S and hold S for X amount of time. I think this may need to be multithreaded but I am not sure how to handle this in python.

This is code I found that tracks the length of a key press. It just needs to be threaded, I think.

```
import time

def callb(key): #what to do on key-release
    ti1 = str(time.time() - t)[0:5] #converting float to str, slicing the float
    print("The key",key," is pressed for",ti1,'seconds')
    return False #stop detecting more key-releases
def callb1(key): #what to do on key-press
    return False #stop detecting more key-presses

with keyboard.Listener(on_press = callb1) as listener1: #setting code for listening key-press
    listener1.join()

t = time.time() #reading time in sec

with keyboard.Listener(on_release = callb) as listener: #setting code for listening key-release
    listener.join()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hook method to get all events

```
import keyboard

HISTORY = {}


def key_recording(e):
    if e.name not in HISTORY and e.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN:
        HISTORY[e.name] = e.time
    elif e.name in HISTORY and e.event_type == keyboard.KEY_UP:
        print(f"The key {e.name} is pressed for {round(e.time - HISTORY.pop(e.name), 3)} seconds")


remove = keyboard.hook(key_recording)
try:
    input("Press any key to exit")
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
finally:
    remove()
```

Comment: Compiling and running this code results in no output or logging. It compiles then goes to next terminal line looking for a command. Am I missing something?